# Fail while trying to set a new element in a Hashtable using loop for

Tags: c

I'm trying to set a hashtable with new elements:
So I created an array `ligne[3][25] = {NULL}`, and :

```
strcpy(ligne[0] , "mama");
strcpy(ligne[1] , "kaka");
strcpy(ligne[2] , "tata");
```

When adding an elemnt into the hashtable using **ligne** : It works :)

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
            ht_set(hashtable, ligne[i] );
        }
```

But ... When I tried to be flexible and read the elements from a text file, the hashtable have only the last element of the text file , take a look :

```
FILE* file = fopen("dico.txt", "r");
while (fgets(ligne[i], 25, file) != NULL ){
            i++;
        }

        for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
            ht_set(hashtable, ligne[i] );
        }
```

The hashtable only conatins :

```
tata
```

The text file **dico.txt** contains :

```
mama
kaka
tata
```

**My function that add an element is ht_set(hashtable , element)**

```
* Insert a value into a hash table. */
entry_t* ht_set( hashtable_t *hashtable, char *key ) {
    int bin = 0;
    entry_t *newpair = NULL;
    entry_t *next = NULL;
    entry_t *last = NULL;

    bin = ht_hash( hashtable, key );

    next = hashtable->table[ bin ];

    while( next != NULL && next->key != NULL ) {
        last = next;
        next = next->next;
    }

    /* There's already a pair.  Let's replace that string. */
    if( next != NULL && next->key != NULL) {

        free( next->key );
        next->key = strdup( key );
        return next;


    /* Nope, could't find it.  Time to grow a pair. */
    } else {
        newpair = ht_newpair( key );

        /* We're at the start of the linked list in this bin. */
        if( next == hashtable->table[ bin ] ) {
            newpair->next = next;
            hashtable->table[ bin ] = newpair;

        /* We're at the end of the linked list in this bin. */
        } else if ( next == NULL ) {
            last->next = newpair;

        /* We're in the middle of the list. */
        } else  {
            newpair->next = next;
            last->next = newpair;
        }
        return newpair;
    }
}
```

**My code is :**

```
int main(int argc,char* argv []){
    hashtable_t* hashtable = ht_create(62400);
    int i=0;
    char ligne[3][25]= {NULL}; // three char pointer that take each ligne
    FILE* file = fopen("dico.txt", "r");
    if(file != NULL){
        while (fgets(ligne[i], 25, file) != NULL ){
            i++;
        }

        for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
            ht_set(hashtable, ligne[i] );
        }
        printf("%s ", ht_get(hashtable , "mama"));// Search "mama" in the hashtable if exist then write it if not exist then printf (null)
    }
    free(hashtable);
    fclose(file);
    return  0;
}
```

Thank you for you helps, that took me 5 days and I really  can't resolve it LOL lol

Comment: The code above does not appear to show the error, or it is not readily apparent from it. Please post a MCVE. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Increment number of strings read in while loop into another variable like `cnt` and use it in `for` loop. It looks you are using `i` incorrectly both in `while` followed by `for` loops.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tonious/1377667, you have changed something without knowing what..